Block all internet connections when OpenVPN connection drops
We use OpenBSD 7.6 and have an OpenVPN connection, made by pkg_add openvpn (openvpn-2.6.12) and writing this into /etc/hostname.tun0 and rebooting after saving:
up
!/usr/local/sbin/openvpn --daemon --config /etc/openvpn/my-config.ovpn

Our public IP is that of the OpenVPN server when checked (good). However, when the connection to the OpenVPN server drops, internet traffic leaks out of the VPN and our public IP here is seen instead, (bad)
How can we configure this computer so that all traffic sent to/from the internet goes exclusively through the OpenVPN connection, and if that connection is interrupted/not-connected, any internet access attempts are blocked?

ifconfig shows we have bcm0 as our ethernet and tun0 as our OpenVPN connection. This computer has only one ethernet port.

netstat -R shows we only have one Rdomain, 0, and interfaces lo0 bge0 enc0 tun0 pflog0 are under it with routing tables of only 0.

We still need access to the computer via local IPs, regardless if OpenVPN connection is established/interrupted/not-connected.


I have looked through route, rdomain, trunk, ifconfig, openvpn manuals but cannot get this to work right.
I've tried adding rdomain 0 to /etc/hostname.tun0 and rdomain 1 to /etc/hostname.bge0 and restarting but that broke local SSH connections (I had to revert these changes to repair that).
In summary: we need to block all internet traffic from all processes unless the OpenVPN connection is established. Local IP traffic is the only thing that can/should work regardless of that connection, due to local IPs resolving to local devices and nothing on the OpenVPN server (which we don't control).

Note: in the future we may use Wireguard protocol instead, or in addition to this OpenVPN connection, and either connection shall be permitted (or possibly one software through WG exclusively, one through OVPN exclusively). We do not want any internet data leaking beyond VPNs and prefer blocked connections in those cases.

Also, please be patient, as we are new to openBSD! :)

Have you configured /etc/pf.conf? This file defines firewall and routing rules on OpenBSD.

Like how you need to specify the local interface (bge0) and the VPN interface (tun0):
ext_if="bge0"
vpn_if="tun0.

@security_paranoid Oh! I have not. I will specify those 2 lines in /etc/pf.conf and add pf=YES to my /etc/rc.conf.local (saw somewhere to do this also) and will report back

@security_paranoid A few things: I discovered pf=YES is enabled by default in modern openBSD--no changes needed there. ......... I added ext_if = "bge0" and vpn_if = "tun0" to /etc/pf.conf and also commented out pass near the top to block all traffic, but now I'm not sure where to go from here.
